Type of British porcelain invented around 1917-1918
Being subscribed already for 30 years on Scientific American, I recently downloaded the whole archive, and I am now going through 1914-1918.
In the 26 January 1918 issue, on page 95, there is a small article talking about a "New Type of English Hard Porcelain". This was apparently created at the Central School of Science and Technology in Stoke-on-Trent, see full text below.
This piqued my curiosity. Which kind of porcelain would this be (it's not named in the article) and did it have a lingering technological influence?

New Type of English Hard Porcelain
NEW type of hard porcelain that possess two important advantages has been evolved through researches undertaken by the Central School of Science and Technology in Stoke-on-Trent. The experimenters sought to produce a hard porcelain made wholly of British materials and to compound a body that would “pot” like ordinary earthenware. Specimens of ware exhibited show that both these objects have been accomplished.
The body of the new porcelain is as cheap as or cheaper than ordinary earthenware. The glaze (leadless) is about one-tenth the price of earthenware glaze. Particular satisfaction is expressed with the glaze, which, when fired under suitable conditions, seems equal to anything yet marketed. The firing margin is very large. The oven which was built for experiments—an entirely new type—has proved a great success, and there is no reason why a development of this oven might not be used in the production of ordinary earthenware.
Little difficulty was anticipated with the fire clays, since it was known that there are many suitable fire clays in the country. The saggers used have stood remarkably well, in fact, not more than two or three saggers were lost in over 20 firings to temperatures ranging from Cone No. 10 to Cone No. 16.
The ware produced is capable of being successfully decorated with ordinary colors. People acquainted with hard porcelain know that this is not possible with some types. A great defect attaching to the Continental hard porcelain is the limitation of the colors that can be applied.
The firing of the new porcelain is the point that will be regarded most seriously by the manufacturer contemplating its production. The new ware can be fired in either “oxidizing” or “reducing” atmospheres, but the best results are obtained by the “reducing" method, which will involve important modifications in the firing practice now obtaining.
Many interesting problems in connection with the firing have arisen and much work has yet to be done. At present the experimenters are concentrating on faults in manufacture, so that the more probable sources of difficulties and losses will be known. The examination of these is necessarily slow, as it is not possible to fire oftener than once a week if they are to fire under ordinary manufacturing conditions.


I did a quick search on Google Scholar targeting the 1915-1925 period but didn't get anything relevant (many art and galleries exposition reports but not much chemically speaking). Maybe you could improve your question by providing the complete article? (If it isn't too long, use an OCR and post the text as quote in your question) It may help us in finding adequate keywords...

@mranvick I found the page image and added OCRed text for the full article, but it looks more like an ad with too little details to pin down the sort of material, structure, or manufacturing process. Maybe someone else will. Maybe looking into powder XRD analysis data done on these ceramics could help.

If you don't get a satisfactory answer here, you might ask at an art gallery or museum school, See a query such as https://search.brave.com/search?q=schoool+of+fine+arts+ceramics for some ideas.

Thanks for the response. About the article itself, it's probably out of copyright, but I still didn't dare to include it. Thanks, @andselisk. And also thanks to the others for pointing to other probable specialists.
